# Outlook Express 6 changed to Microsoft Outlook 97

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I started exporting messages from Outlook Express 6 by option 'export' in the 'file' section. When it started I noticed the time would take too long and I canceled it.

Right after that OE6 crashed. Now, when I open it again, MS Outlook 97 starts instead of OE 6 (with only a few messages I exported).

How do I go back to OE 6 with all my messages?

Comment: "when I open it again"  How? You are using a shortcut, what are its properties?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove Outlook 97 and then see if OE6 works again. However... my guts tell me that if you still have Outlook 97 installed on your computer, you're not that computer savvy. If that's the case, find someone who can help you do this, someone who is able to fix things when it gets even more messy. Removing Outlook 97 might break more, and it's good to have someone close who can prepare for that, by making a backup or an image of the harddisk or something else.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Outlook Express shortcut is broken.

If you're on Windows XP, you can run Outlook Express directly, by doing

1. WindowsKey+R (or Start then Run)
2. Enter msimn.exe and click Ok

(Trivia: msimn stands for Microsoft Internet Mail and News)